# Invalid Selector Error using CSS Selector and href

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to find an element using css selector and href with a partail link but I keep getting an invalid selector error

What am I doing wrong?

```
<a href="javascript:shipdateCheck('updateShipDate',#####,'false');" class="actionlink2">
    <img src="images/save-16x16.bmp" width="12px" height="12px" alt="Update 
     Ship Date For ######" border="0">
</a>
```

the ##### is a number as a string that is randomly generated.

```
date_save = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[href*="javascript:shipdateCheck("updateShipDate","]')
```

Comment: Could you add the html of the element you are looking for?

Comment: I added the HTML of the element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo of having a **`*`** in href. Also if you do not use the actual equals value then you can use contains. If you have double quotes inside double quotes you need to escape them with \".

```
date_save = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[contains(@href, "javascript:shipdateCheck(\"updateShipDate\",")]')
```

Comment: I have used the *= before to say that the element begins with the string. Does it not work with href? It works for name and type

Comment: You have mixed CSS selector syntax with XPath syntax in your answer. All that was needed was to escape the inner `"`s and add the missing `)` and it should work. `contains()` is an XPath method.

Answer (score 0):

To click on anchor tag induce `WebDriverWait()` and `element_to_be_clickable()` and following css selector.

```
WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"a[href*=\"javascript:shipdateCheck('updateShipDate'\"]"))).click()
```

You need to import following libraries.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```